# How to store an env file in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to set a bunch of env variables in a file and trying to use the command `gcloud run deploy ... --env-vars-file=.env.yaml` to load/use the file. I'm running the command from google cloudshell console within the browser(eventually I will be using cloud build) and so I want to store this file in google cloud and access it in this command using its file path. I tried storing the file in a cloud storage and trying to access it like this
`gcloud run deploy <appname> --image <imageurl> --env-vars-file gs://<cloudstorage name>/.env.yaml` . But it is throwing an error saying "Unable to read file".

I understand the problem is with storing the file in a location accessible by the google cloudshell. I'm trying to find out which is the best way to store and retrieve the file in google cloud.

Note: I'm using the below yaml file for my build. (gsutil cp script added as  as per the input provided by Kolban)

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', '<image-url>' ]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', '<image-url>']
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'gsutil'
  args: ['cp', 'gs://my-storage/dev.env.yaml', '/tmp/dev.env.yaml']
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'gcloud'
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'my-app', '--image', '<image-url>', '--env-vars-file', '/tmp/dev.env.yaml']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the docs on the [gcloud run deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--env-vars-file) command we find:

> Path to a local YAML file with definitions for all environment variables. All existing environment variables will be removed before the new environment variables are added.

The key part is that the file is the path to a *local* file.  This would be a file on the local file system where gcloud is run.  Google Cloud Storage isn't considered local storage.

Some choices would be:

1. Run `gsutil cp` to copy the GCS file to local storage (eg. /tmp) prior to running gcloud and then pass the local file name.
2. Run `gsutil cat` to echo/display the content of the file and then use `--set-env-vars` using the output.  This is likely going to mean that your environment file stored in GCS has to be of the right format.

Of these notions, I like the first the best.  Something like the following:

```
tfile = $(mktemp)
gsutil cp gs://GCSFILEPATH ${tfile}
gcloud ... --env-vars-file=${tfile}
rm ${tfile}
```

On the second part of your question ... if you are using Cloud Build and are running a sequence of steps, understand that these steps run in their own Docker container and hence their own filesystems.  If we read [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/pass-data-between-steps) we will find documentation on sharing data between steps using the file system.  In simple terms and by default, the directory `/workspace` is shared between each steps.  If a file in a step writes into `/workspace` that file will be seen by subsequent steps.

In your example, change `/tmp/dev.env.yaml` to `/workspace/dev.env.yaml` and your will have better success.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Now I'm trying to add these steps to a yaml file, but it fails there. I guess the two commands are running separately in different machines which is causing this. Is there a work around for this?

- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'gsutil'
  args: ['cp', 'gs://my-storage/dev.env.yaml', '/tmp/dev.env.yaml']
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'gcloud'
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'myapp', '--image', '<image-url>', '--env-vars-file', ' /tmp/dev.env.yaml']

Comment: Ahh ... when you say "Add these steps to a yaml file ..." is this for "Cloud Build"?   Can you shared (publicly) your Cloud Build script (remove anything sensitive).  I think the question may be turning into sharing data between multiple Cloud Build steps.

Comment: I have added my Yaml file contents to the question description. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated answer with more text

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your help.

One followup question: Will the files in /workspace gets cleared automatically? is there a way to clear them manually? I tried executing rm command as a bash script step in yaml script but it is erroring out.

/workspace

Comment: At the end of the Cloud Build job, the /workspace environment is disposed of.  You should not need to cleanup.